# Не могу включить register_argc_argv на удаленном сервере

Tags: php

Собственно, все сказал в Теме.

Сервер собран как CGI.

Для корректной работы скрипта через консоль хочу включить директиву `register_argc_argv` в `php.ini`
Выполняю следующий код:

```
if (!ini_get('register_argc_argv')) {
    if(ini_set('register_argc_argv', '1')){
        echo "Установилось \n";
    } else {
        echo "Не удалось установить \n";
    }
}
```

Выдает: "Не удалось установить"

Причем, был такой момент, что все заработало - но это был лишь миг.

Пробовал в самом файле php.ini менять эту директиву, но она там включена по умолчанию. Что еще может ее выключить?

Весь код файла выглядит так (это фрэймворк Yii2):

```
#!/***/shared/php55/bin/php-cgi
<?php
/**
 * Yii console bootstrap file.
 *
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */
if (!ini_get('register_argc_argv')) {
    if(ini_set('register_argc_argv', '1')){
        echo "Установилось \n";
    } else {
        echo "Не удалось установить \n";
    }
}

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/config/console.php');

var_dump($_SERVER['argv']); // выдает неопределенная переменная
var_dump($argv);            // выдает неопределенная переменная
exit();

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = __DIR__ . '/yii';
$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
$exitCode = $application->run();
exit($exitCode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил заменой первой строки в файле yii на

```
#!/path-to/php55/bin/php-cgi -c path-to/php.ini
```